# How can we use multiple data source for spring batch job

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a problem where I need to use 2 databases in single job. 
Can anyone tell me how can we provide multiple datasources.

Comment: Post your code/configuration. Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of multiple DataSources in Spring Batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25540502/use-of-multiple-datasources-in-spring-batch)