# Setting Spring Batch meta data Repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am running a Spring Batch job and have two DataSource's configured like such:

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
public DataSource mainDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean("SpringBatchDataSource")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.batch.datasource")
public DataSource batchDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

As you can see of the two DataSources I have one is just for the Spring batch metadata.

This issue I'm having is Spring batch wants to use the `@Primary` `DataSource`. How can I configure it to use the batchDataSource?

Comment: You can add `@primary` annotation to the `batchDataSource` method or try changing `batchDataSource` to simply `dataSource`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of multiple DataSources in Spring Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25540502/use-of-multiple-datasources-in-spring-batch)

Comment: @AmitP - Yes, those are two things I don't want to do. Otherwise I would then have to set the non batch metadata datasource all over the place.