# Using multiple datasources in springbatch (spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE) throwing exception on bootup

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to use two datasources, one for metadata tables from spring batch and other is my application database to read/process/write. when I am trying to use both it is giving the following exception.

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: To use the default BatchConfigurer the context must contain no more thanone DataSource, found 2
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.AbstractBatchConfiguration.getConfigurer(AbstractBatchConfiguration.java:108) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration.initialize(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:114) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$ReferenceTargetSource.createObject(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:142) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.AbstractLazyCreationTargetSource.getTarget(AbstractLazyCreationTargetSource.java:86) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:192) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.getJobInstances(Unknown Source)


----------

    import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource;

import com.springbatch_sample.domain.Person;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;



    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource hsqldbDataSource() throws SQLException {
        final SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriver(new org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver());
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/xdb");
        dataSource.setUsername("sa");
        dataSource.setPassword("sa");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(final DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("mysqlDataSource")
    public DataSource mysqlDataSource() throws SQLException {
        final SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriver(new com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver());
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:db2://xxxx");
        dataSource.setUsername("user");
        dataSource.setPassword("pswd");
        //DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(databasePopulator(), dataSource);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<Person>();
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("sample-data.csv"));
        reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<Person>() {{
            setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
                setNames(new String[] { "firstName", "lastName" });
            }});
            setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person>() {{
                setTargetType(Person.class);
            }});
        }});
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersonItemProcessor processor() {
        return new PersonItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer() throws SQLException {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person>();
        writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Person>());
        writer.setSql("INSERT INTO people (first_name, last_name) VALUES (:firstName, :lastName)");
        writer.setDataSource(hsqldbDataSource());
        return writer;
    }
    // end::readerwriterprocessor[]

    // tag::jobstep[]
    @Bean
    public Job importUserJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener) throws SQLException {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .flow(step1())
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() throws SQLException {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Person, Person> chunk(10)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer())
                .build();
    }
    // end::jobstep[]
}
```

Comment: Please add stacktrace. I see for both job metadata and itemWriter you are using HSQL DB?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of multiple DataSources in Spring Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25540502/use-of-multiple-datasources-in-spring-batch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use of multiple DataSources in Spring Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25540502/use-of-multiple-datasources-in-spring-batch)

Check out this link.
Same question, and I solved my problem by that link.