# Spring-boot and spring batch datasources

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, datasource, batch-processing

I want to convert an existing spring-boot application into a spring-boot + spring-batch application. This application should use a separate data source for spring-batch connecting to a separate database. Existing application uses `application.properties` file and I added several batch specific

> spring.batch.datasource.*

properties to `application.properties` file and configured to use it in my bean definitions like these.

```
@Bean(name = "batchDataSource")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "batch")
public DataSource batchDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

I guess I am not doing it in the right way and looking forward to integrate spring-batch which uses a separate data source for spring-batch meta data. Any suggestions on how best we can do this integration in existing spring-boot application?

Comment: what you should do is configure datasources separately manually. Search for how to configure multiple datasources in springboot. There are many articles regarding this already

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of multiple DataSources in Spring Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25540502/use-of-multiple-datasources-in-spring-batch)

Comment: @MichaelMinella Do you think that documentation should be part of spring-batch documentation since most of the people use the batch schema as a different from their business schema?