# Spring batch with quartz configuration not working - Looking for spring metadata table instead of quartz table

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I have requirement to develop a spring boot batch using quartz as scheduler.
I have created spring batch application and also configured quartz to trigger job and persist job/trigger data in quartz related RDBMS tables.

Spring boot application starts successfully but when it triggers the job as per cron config. Its throws below error.

```
2020-04-27 20:42:09.967  INFO 1460 --- [           main] c.b.g.batch.IemsBatchApplication         : Started IemsBatchApplication in 12.112 seconds (JVM running for 13.22)
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

I am not able to find the root cause that why application is trying to persist data in spring meta data table rather than quartz tables.
Quartz related tables are already created in my db.
Please help me.

Please find below the code for the same.

```
    @Configuration
   public class BatchSchedulerConfig {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("batchDataSource")
private DataSource batchDataSource;
@Autowired
JobLauncher jobLauncher;
@Autowired
JobLocator jobLocator;

@Bean
public JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactoryBean() {
    JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactoryBean = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
    jobDetailFactoryBean.setJobClass(BatchJobLauncherConfig.class);
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("jobName", IEMSBatchConstant.MonthlyElectricityMeterReadingJob);
    jobDetailFactoryBean.setJobDataAsMap(map);
    jobDetailFactoryBean.setGroup("etl_group");
    jobDetailFactoryBean.setName("etl_job");
    return jobDetailFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
public CronTriggerFactoryBean cronTriggerFactoryBean(JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactoryBean) {
    CronTriggerFactoryBean cronTriggerFactoryBean = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
    cronTriggerFactoryBean.setJobDetail(jobDetailFactoryBean.getObject());
    cronTriggerFactoryBean.setStartDelay(3000);
    cronTriggerFactoryBean.setName("cron_trigger");
    cronTriggerFactoryBean.setGroup("cron_group");
    cronTriggerFactoryBean.setCronExpression("0 0/2 * 1/1 * ? *");
    return cronTriggerFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean(CronTriggerFactoryBean cronTriggerFactoryBean) throws IOException {

    SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("joblocator", jobLocator);
    map.put("JobLauncher", jobLauncher);
    scheduler.setSchedulerContextAsMap(map);
    scheduler.setTriggers(cronTriggerFactoryBean.getObject());
    scheduler.setDataSource(batchDataSource);
    scheduler.setQuartzProperties(quartzProperties());
    // scheduler.setSchedulerName(schedulerName);
    return scheduler;
}

public Properties quartzProperties() throws IOException {
    PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/quartz.properties"));
    propertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return propertiesFactoryBean.getObject();
}
```

}

```
    @Configuration
   @EnableConfigurationProperties
  public class BatchBaseConfig {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchBaseConfig.class);

@Bean
public JobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) throws Exception {
    SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    simpleJobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    return simpleJobLauncher;
}

@Bean
public JobRepository jobRepository(DataSource batchDataSource) throws Exception {
    DataSourceTransactionManager batchTransactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
    JobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactoryBean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
    batchTransactionManager.setDataSource(batchDataSource);
    jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(batchTransactionManager);
    jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setDatabaseType(DatabaseType.ORACLE.getProductName());
    //jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_DEFAULT");
    jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setDataSource(batchDataSource);
    jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTablePrefix("QRTZ_");
    jobRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return jobRepositoryFactoryBean.getObject();
}

@Bean(name = "batchDataSource")
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "quartz")
public DataSource batchDataSource() {
    DataSource batchDbSrc = DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    return batchDbSrc;
}

@Bean(name = "appDataSource")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app")
public DataSource appDataSource() {
    DataSource appDbSrc = DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    return appDbSrc;
}

@Bean
public JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor(JobRegistry jobRegistry) {
    JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor = new JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor();
    jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
    return jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor;
}
```

}

```
   @Getter
   @Setter
 public class BatchJobLauncherConfig extends QuartzJobBean {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchJobLauncherConfig.class);

private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
private JobLocator joblocator;
private String jobName;

@Override
protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {

    try {
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(joblocator.getJob(jobName), new 
   JobParameters());
        log.info("{}_{} was completed successfully", jobExecution.getJobConfigurationName(), 
    jobExecution.getId());
    } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | 
        JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException
            | JobParametersInvalidException | NoSuchJobException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

```
    @Configuration
  public class JobConfig {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JobConfig.class);
@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
@Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
@Autowired
private ReadingFromDB readingFromDB;
@Autowired
private ReadingFileWriter readingFileWriter;

@Qualifier(value = "meterReadingJob")
@Bean
public Job meterReadingJob() throws Exception {
    log.info("Enter into meterReadingJob method ");
    return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("meterReadingJob")
            .start(createReadingFile()).build();
}

@Bean
public Step createReadingFile() throws Exception {
    return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("createReadingFile").chunk(1)
            .reader(readingFromDB).writer(readingFileWriter).build();

}
```

}

Application.properties

```
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
#Spring's default configuration to generate datasource
app.jdbcUrl=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//<Removed>
app.username=<Removed>
app.password=<Removed>
app.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.app.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

 #Quartz dataSource
quartz.jdbcUrl=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//<Removed>
quartz.username=<Removed>
quartz.password=<Removed>
quartz.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

Quartz.properties

```
 #scheduler name will be "MyScheduler"
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=MyNewScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO

#maximum of 3 jobs can be run simultaneously
org.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=50

#Quartz persistent jobStore config
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=QRTZ_
#org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=batchDataSource
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=false
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=false
```

Both datasources are getting created and entries are also going for triggers and jobs in datasource names batchDataSource. 
Issue comes when job gets triggered and batch tries to insert job details in DB.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Spring Batch needs database tables to run. https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/schema-appendix.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of multiple DataSources in Spring Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25540502/use-of-multiple-datasources-in-spring-batch)

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Yes , i understand that but i am using quartz to trigger spring batch. it should look for quartz tables.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I am able to configure both databases in my application. After running application i can see both datasources are alive.