# No Exception when Spring batch tables are not created

Tags: spring-batch

If the BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT was not created all I get is :

> Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT (SHORT_CONTEXT, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT, JOB_EXECUTION_ID) VALUES(?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

the error above is displayed while inserting into the table, but at the moment of the creation of the table (done automatically by spring batch )no error was displayed.

I would like to know the reason way the table was not created so I could know what is  the issue (database permissions, problems of tablespace...) is it possible to log it in traces?

for information I'm using oracle database 12C and ojdbc8 version 12.2.0.1

Comment: `at the moment of the creation of the table no error was displayed.`. How are you creating the tables?

Comment: I mean when spring batch wants to create the tables, because as far as I know spring batch create all 'table batch ' automatically when you run a project

Comment: Ok, this is where I wanted to come. Spring Batch assumes tables are already created in your datasource. You need to create them manually upfront or tell Spring Boot to create them for you using the `spring.batch.initialize-schema` property. See my answer for more details. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring Batch does not automatically create meta-data tables in your datasource. You need to run the [tables creation script](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core) against your database manually.

However, if you use Spring Boot, those tables can be created automatically using the `spring.batch.initialize-schema` property. More details here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-initialize-a-spring-batch-database

There are similar/related questions to this one, I'm adding them for reference here:

- [Spring Batch Framework - Auto create Batch Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33249942/spring-batch-framework-auto-create-batch-table)
- [Spring Batch doesn't use custom datasource to create tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43655213/spring-batch-doesnt-use-custom-datasource-to-create-tables)

Comment: If you use Spring Boot the variable that you must use depends on the version. For example with Spring Boot v1.5.14.RELEASE, Spring v4.3.18.RELEASE you should use:
spring.batch.initializer.enabled=false

Answer (score 2):

Check your Spring Boot starter class or configuration class and make sure you are not excluding this auto configuration:

```
(exclude={BatchAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Also make sure this property is not set to `never`:

```
spring.batch.initialize-schema
```

Answer (score 2):

spring.batch.initialize-schema is deprecated and instead of using it use:

spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always