# Spring batch Jobparamaters with file name

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I want to create project with spring batch rest controller and dynamic input filename.

My code : Rest Controller

```
@RestController
```

public class FileNameController {

```
@Autowired
JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@Autowired
Job job;

@RequestMapping("/launchjob")
public String handle(@RequestParam("fileName") String fileName) throws Exception {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    try {
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                                                    .addString("input.file.name", fileName)
                                                    .addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
                                                    .toJobParameters();
        jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
    }

    return "Done";
}
```

}

The Job config:

```
@Configuration
```

@EnableBatchProcessing
public class JobConfig {

```
@Autowired
public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;


 Filetasklet ft=new Filetasklet();
 Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());


private String pathFile = urlCoffreFort + "\\" + ft.getFileName();

// => Configuration of Job  
        @Bean
        public Job job() throws IOException {
                    return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                    .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                    .flow(step1())
                    .end()
                    .build();
        }

        //###### Steps          
        // => Step cecStep1
        @Bean
        public Step step1() throws IOException {
            return stepBuilderFactory.get("fileDecrypt")
                    .<Person, String>chunk(100)
                    .reader(reader1())
                    .processor(processor1FileDecrypt())
                    .writer(writer1())
                    .faultTolerant()
                    .skip(Exception.class)
                    .skipLimit(100)
                    .build();
        }
        // ####### readers 

        // => reader1()
        @Bean
        public FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader1() throws IOException{

            return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<CSCivique>().name("personItemReader")
                                        .resource(new ClassPathResource(pathFile))
                                        .delimited()
                                        .delimiter(";")
                                        .names(new String[] { "id",  "nomNaissance", "prenom" })
                                        .targetType(CSCivique.class)
                                        .build();
        }

        // ######Processors             

        @Bean
        public PersonItemProcessor1FileDecrypt processor1FileDecrypt() {
            return new PersonItemProcessor1FileDecrypt();
        }

        // ######Writers 

        @Bean
        public FlatFileItemWriter<String> writer1() {
            return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<String>().name("greetingItemWriter")
                    .resource(new FileSystemResource("sav/greetings.csv"))
                    .lineAggregator(new PassThroughLineAggregator<>()).build();
        }
```

}

When I write the url :
http://localhost:8080/launchjob?fileName=djecc5cpt.csv
The console print :

PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME =? and JOB_KEY =?]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: the relation "batch_job_instance" does not exist
   Position: 39

Comment: What is not understandable about the error message?

Comment: I do not have a request, normally the framework will create its tables

Comment: I added an answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not have a request, normally the framework will create its tables

Spring Batch won't make the decision to create tables on your behalf in your production database. **You** need to make that decision and do it manually upfront. Otherwise, if you use Spring Boot, you can tell Spring Boot to do it for your by setting `spring.batch.initialize-schema=always`.

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51891852/5019386 for a similar question/answer.