# Spring batch set data source when having 3 datasources without any @Primary

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

My system has got 3 data sources, all exposed as beans named datasourceA, datasourceB, datasourceC. I am trying to set the data source of spring batch to datasourceB but I am getting quite some issues.

My spring batch class

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class JobBatchConfiguration extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void setDataSource(@Qualifier("dataSourceB") DataSource dataSource) {
        super.setDataSource(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public BatchDataSourceInitializer batchDatabaseInitializer(@Qualifier("dataSourceB") DataSource dataSource, ResourceLoader resourceLoader){
        BatchProperties batchProperties = new BatchProperties();
        batchProperties.setInitializeSchema(DataSourceInitializationMode.ALWAYS);
        BatchDataSourceInitializer batchDatabaseInitializer = new  BatchDataSourceInitializer(dataSource, resourceLoader, batchProperties);
        return batchDatabaseInitializer;
    }
}
```

With this setup I am getting this error upon startup

```
Field dataSource in org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.AbstractBatchConfiguration required a single bean, but 3 were found:
Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

I cannot set any of my datasources to @Primary since my spring batch writer reads and writes using all 3 datasources. I am using JPA repository and spring data.

Any solution? I thought overriding setDataSource should be enough

Comment: Hello, if you put `@Autowired` above your setter method is there always the same problem ?

Comment: Which spring batch version do you use? Can you provide a minimal example that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place `@Qualifier` both on your bean definition and in place when the bean is being autowired.

```
// data sources config
@Bean
@Qualifier("dataSourceB")
public DataSource dataSourceB() { ... }

// batch processing config
public void setDataSource(@Qualifier("dataSourceB") DataSource dataSource) { ... }
```

Also, there is no need to use `@Qualifier` because Spring uses a bean name as a fallback qualifier. Cite from https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers:

> For a fallback match, the bean name is considered a default qualifier value.

Thus, you can rename your variable to match the bean name you want to autowire.

```
// data sources config
@Bean
public DataSource dataSourceB() { ... }

// batch processing config
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSourceB) { ... }
```