# Spring Batch multiple DataSourcees

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

In Spring Batch, I can inject a DataSource in

```
@Configuration
public class DbConfiguration {
    ....
    @Autowired
    public DataSource dataSource;
```

With a bunch of properties in my Application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/learning_spring_batch
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=waterside
spring.datasource.platform=mysql
spring.datasource.continueOnError=false
```

What happens if I want multiple Datasources?

For example, 1 for my source, 1 for my target and 1 for my Spring batch tables, is that possible? Also, if I want to specify specific schemas for any of the Datasources how do I do that? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25256487/how-to-java-configure-separate-datasources-for-spring-batch-data-and-business-da

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to java-configure separate datasources for spring batch data and business data? Should I even do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25256487/how-to-java-configure-separate-datasources-for-spring-batch-data-and-business-da)