# How to configure a datasource for a spring batch in Spring Boot 2 for testing purpose

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, datasource

I am playing with a simple batch processing and I have a problem with a DataSource configuration despite having an H2 dependency.

Output from the console:

```
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
```

My classes operates on Strings and use:

```
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
```

Main

```
@SpringBootApplication   
public class Boo2BatchApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Boo2BatchApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Config:

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {

    @Bean
    public Step recordsStep(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, RecordReader recordReader,
            RecordProcessor<String> recordProcessor, RecordWriter recordWriter) {

        return stepBuilderFactory.get("recordsSetp").<String, String>chunk(4).reader(recordReader)
                .processor(recordProcessor).writer(recordWriter).build();
    }

    @Bean
    Job recordsJob(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, Step recordsStep) {

        return jobBuilderFactory.get("recordsJob").start(recordsStep).build();
    }

}
```

Comment: did you add h2 driver to your project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to java-configure separate datasources for spring batch data and business data? Should I even do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25256487/how-to-java-configure-separate-datasources-for-spring-batch-data-and-business-da)

Comment: The H2 dependency is sufficient. No additional configuration is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a Database like H2 is on the path the DataSource is configured by default (as @Alireza Khajavi said). No additional configuration is needed. My classpath was messed up and the dependency from a pom file was not available during startup.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Is your issue solved now that you figured out that your classpath was messed up?